# Получение ID из другой таблицы

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных

Доброго времени суток!
Есть две таблицы `customers` с полями `id_сustomer`, `last_name` и тд (не имеет значения), и есть таблица `orders` c полями `id_order`, `id_customer` и т.д. 
В поле `id_customer` таблицы `orders` стоит `comboBox` при добавлении. Нужно чтобы в этот `comboBox` при добавлении считывались значения из `id_customer` таблицы `customers`.

Читала оф документацию, наткнулась на следующий код, не совсем уверена подходит ли он в данной ситуации, т.к на данном участке кода при компиляции возникает ошибка на требовании ссылки для не статического поля на объект `comboBox1`. Прошу поправить код, указать на ошибки.

```
static void GetList(SqlConnection connection)
{ 
    using (connection)
    {           
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM customers;",connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                 comboBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }           
        reader.Close();
```

Comment: уберите слово `static` из определения функции

Comment: Тут не дело в ошибке, в самом коде который на работает, и в сути вопроса, который я задала выше.